# How to integrate python with SAP ABAP

Tags: python-3.x, abap

I want to integrate python with ABAP. Actually, What I did I have a python script and I made it as Flask app. After that I deployed python flask application to Docker and it running on Docker server. So now by using this service I can connect to this python script. Is there any other ways. Which is best and effective in performance wise. Please let me know

Comment: Does that mean you can expose the functionality of the Python script via a webservice?

Comment: yes, I made python script as webservice

Comment: you wanna reach this service from ABAP?

Comment: I already reached this service from ABAP. I want to know any other ways better than this

Comment: Every third party tool out of the SAP will get a lot of pain. Because Basis teams cannot monitor or check your third party tool. They will make changes on SAP side with out inform you. You can use SAP out of the box service consume or publish functionality. If you have a lot of connection you can use SAP XI/PO or other alternatives. Last thing: never forget license issues. If you create document from third party tools, you will get extra cost for user license.